# Why can't I reverse a split-range using range-v3?

Tags: c++, range-v3

I want to split, reverse, and then join a string using range-v3. However, code below won't compile.

```cpp
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace ranges;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto str = std::string("abc.def.ghi");
    auto sv = str
              | view::split('.')
              | view::reverse
              | view::join('.');
    std::cout<<sv;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('decltype(pipeable_access::impl<view<reverse_fn> >::pipe(static_cast<ranges::v3::split_view<ranges::v3::iterator_range<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > >, std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >, ranges::v3::view::split_fn::element_pred<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > &> > &&>(arg), pipe))' (aka 'void') and 'decltype(make_view(view_access::impl<join_fn>::bind(this->view_, static_cast<char &&>(ts))))' (aka 'view<ranges::v3::detail::pipeable_binder<std::_Binder<std::_Unforced, ranges::v3::view::join_fn &, const std::_Ph<1> &, char> > >'))
range\v3\view\any_view.hpp:60: candidate function not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'decltype(pipeable_access::impl<view<reverse_fn> >::pipe(static_cast<ranges::v3::split_view<ranges::v3::iterator_range<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > >, std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >, ranges::v3::view::split_fn::element_pred<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > &> > &&>(arg), pipe))' (aka 'void') to 'ranges::v3::category' for 1st argument
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\regex:1219: candidate function not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'decltype(pipeable_access::impl<view<reverse_fn> >::pipe(static_cast<ranges::v3::split_view<ranges::v3::iterator_range<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > >, std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >, ranges::v3::view::split_fn::element_pred<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > &> > &&>(arg), pipe))' (aka 'void') to 'std::_Node_flags' for 1st argument
range\v3\utility\functional.hpp:725: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Arg = void, Pipe = ranges::v3::view::view<ranges::v3::detail::pipeable_binder<std::_Binder<std::_Unforced, ranges::v3::view::join_fn &, const std::_Ph<1> &, char> > >, _concept_requires_724 = false, $3 = nullptr]: cannot form a reference to 'void'
range\v3\utility\functional.hpp:734: candidate template ignored: requirement 'false || (is_pipeable<void>() && is_pipeable<ranges::v3::view::view<ranges::v3::detail::pipeable_binder<std::_Binder<std::_Unforced, ranges::v3::view::join_fn &, const std::_Ph<1> &, char> > > >())' was not satisfied [with Pipe0 = void, Pipe1 = ranges::v3::view::view<ranges::v3::detail::pipeable_binder<std::_Binder<std::_Unforced, ranges::v3::view::join_fn &, const std::_Ph<1> &, char> > >, _concept_requires_733 = false]
```

Found a way of doing this:

```cpp
    auto temp_container = str
              | view::split('.')
              | ::ranges::to_vector
              | action::reverse
              ;
    std::string output = temp_container 
              | view::all
              | view::join('.')
              ;
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure they broke something, since now simple `ranges::view::group_by` seems to not work at all. I believe the problem lies in the fact that they might've broken *ranges of ranges*, but I cannot confirm.

Comment: @Fureeish None of the `ranges-v3` versions available on godbolt (`0.3.0`, `0.3.5`, `0.3.6`, `trunk`) compile this code snippet (on either `gcc` or `clang`). Example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/oqoUZE). But I also don't know what time frames you are thinking of when you say "now".

Comment: @MaxLanghof talking about 0.5.0 release. Godbolt also does not compile simple `group_by`s. Given the fact that ranges are still in development, I wouldn't want to try guessing what's wrong as of now. The code should work.

Comment: Range-v3's `view::group_by` tests are passing. What is not working for you @Fureeish?

Comment: You can't pipe a temporary container into a view adaptor because it would create dangling references. Save the vector into a named variable first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`view::split` returns either a an input range or a forward range depending on the adapted range. `view::reverse` requires at least a bidirectional range in order to iterate it backwards.

In principle it would be possible to implement a `split_view` that is a bidirectional range. The problem is that the constructor would already need a complete traversal of the adapted range to find the last element, making it an o(n) operation. And as far as I know the construction of views is required to be o(1).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I think there could be something like `as_list` or `as_vector`, so we can pipe the operations like `split | as_vector | reverse | join` when hold the o(1) construction of view.

Comment: @joyqat: You can't have O(1) construction because it's a *vector*. Building it must perform `O(n)` copies. So you may as well just stick the result of `split` in a vector, then apply `reverse` and `join`. Why does it all need to be on one line?

Comment: @NicolBolas Because such pipe operations can eliminate temporaries and be robust, I think. Moreover, it's really cool if I can do that using c++. :P

Comment: @joyqat there are `ranges::to_vector` and `range::to<Container>`to construct a `std::vector` or an arbitrary `Container` from a range. But you cannot pipe it like that since `to_vector` returns a temporary vector that is a rvalue which are not pipeable with views. So you will have to store the vector as an intermediate result. This is a good thing since it would produce dangling references otherwise.

Comment: @joyqat: How would you eliminate the temporary? Being able to reverse it requires that it first has to be built, and therefore must allocate memory and copy-initialize every element. The resulting container must then be used by every subsequent operation in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that, by *(a)* reversing the string_view, then *(b)* splitting, then *(c)* reversing the inner sub-strings, then *(d)* joining them all back.

This may be achieved with ranges-v3, but here is the C++23 version:

```
auto sv = "abc.def.ghi"sv;
auto str = sv
          | views::reverse
          | views::split('.')
          | views::transform(views::reverse)
          | views::join_with('.')
          | to<std::string>();
std::cout << str;
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qo6qf8WxG

---

Note that in the more general case, where the delimiter may have more than a single char, when splitting on it we need to reverse the delimiter also. Thus the code would be:

```
auto sv = "abc->def->ghi"sv;
auto delim = "->"sv;
auto str = sv
          | views::reverse
          | views::split(views::reverse(delim)) // <== here
          | views::transform(views::reverse)
          | views::join_with(delim)
          | to<std::string>();
std::cout << str;
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M7xqjcMMc

---

To compare above approach, with another approach of splitting into a vector of words then reversing the vector (not seen here, you can see the code in the benchmark link below) -- intuitively and by watching generated assembly it seems that the approach that doesn't need the vector would have better performance. But to get the notion of how better, potentially, here is a [benchmark result](https://quick-bench.com/q/8J-zCXiv0hP71kJuakme-pOS8B8):

[image]